# SQL Join another table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I have a function that queries a table of student scores and return their total score, grade, registration number and score rank(position). I want to write an Sql join that will use the registration number returned from the scores table to get student names from the student table but the names are not returned and i am not getting any error.

```
public function get_subject_result(){

        $subjectID = $this->input->get('subjectID');
        $termID = $this->input->get('termID');
        $sessionID = $this->input->get('sessionID');

        //This Query which gave me headache actually ranks the total score and return positions
        //$this->db->query("JOIN student ON main.stud_reg = student.reg");
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
            FROM result ref
            WHERE ref.total > main.total AND subject_id='".$subjectID."' AND term_id='".$termID."' AND session_id='".$sessionID."') as rank, ca1, ca2, exam,
            total, remark, stud_reg, grade, subject_id
            FROM result main JOIN student ON main.stud_reg = student.reg WHERE subject_id='".$subjectID."' AND term_id='".$termID."' AND session_id='".$sessionID."'
            ORDER BY total DESC");


        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you print the error you got?

Comment: Can you provide information of both tables (fields and pk + fk)?

Comment: Your SELECT clause doesn't include the columns for the student name.

Comment: Do you have WHERE before FROM? scrap that, It's subquery :) sorry

Comment: Include the student name in the select part, use aliases for all the tables and use alias.field everywhere. Readability and maintainability will be greatly improved that way.

Comment: Also, use [parameterization](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) especially if those values derive from user input and break lines by clauses in your multiple-line SQL.